# Can no longer run ruby on osx

Tags: ruby, macos, bundler

I tried to run a ruby script that I have run many time before, but received the following error:

```
~/dev/ruby > ruby foo.rb
Could not find backports-2.3.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
~/dev/ruby > bundle install
Could not find backports-2.3.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
~/dev/ruby > rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-1.8.6-p399 [ i686 ]
   ruby-1.8.7-p249 [ i686 ]
   ruby-1.8.7-p334 [ i686 ]
   ruby-1.9.1-p378 [ i386 ]
=> ruby-1.9.2-p180 [ x86_64 ]
 * ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.2-preview1 [ i386 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p125 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

I have not changed any of my RVM settings since running this program last and have not done anything with backports-2.3.0.

I am currently running OSX 10.6.8 with RVM 1.10.3. I am getting the error when trying to execute any `ruby` commands.

Comment: What happens when you run irb?

Comment: What happens when you try using other ruby versions?

Comment: @Maz, running irb yields the same message  Could not find backports-2.3.0 in any of the sources  
    Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

Comment: @garbagecollection I tried to run both     rvm ruby-1.9.2-p290 yields  Could not find rack-1.3.5 in any of the sources
    
    rvm ruby-1.9.2-p180 yields  Could not find backports-2.3.0 in any of the sources

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to include `source :rubygems` at the top of your Gemfile.

Comment: what happens when you try `gem update --system` and then `gem install backports -v '2.3.0'`?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Gemfile, ensure it reads this

```
gem "backports", "~> 2.3.0"
```

then run bundle again. 
If the problem persists try

```
sudo gem uninstall backports
```

then run bundle install again.

Comment: sudo gem uninstall backports
    Password:
    ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
        cannot uninstall, check `gem list -d backports`
     ~/dev/ruby > gem list -d backports
Could not find rack-1.3.5 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

Comment: hmm... very pecuilar it looks like something important is missing, look through the list and try installing the dependencies one at a time, gem should have figured it out but something might be messed up elsewhere. Starting with rack.

Comment: Unfortunately the only thing worse than having a bug and not knowing why is a problem that disappears and not knowing why.